# Same source code, same database ( and SQL Server machine), fast localhost, very slow in production

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I've the following structure:

MVC 4 Website that uses WCF to access a logic layer.
Then this logic layer uses Entity Framework 4 to get data from SQL Server 2008.

In Localhost one specific page is talking around 3 seconds to load.

However the same source code is taking 15 seconds in production (website is in the same machine as the logic layer and SQL Server.)

In both tests I am using the exact same SQL Server.

Could someone point me in the right direction to fix this???

Comment: Only thing I can think of is profile and measure.. You have to find out what the bottleneck is. Execution of inefficient SQL queries  or the WCF communication via HTTP for example. Question that rises is, why do you use WCF, which in turn uses HTTP, for communication with application logic? Any reason you're not using different assemblies with references to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/ for measure your site?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it. I've tried however, the places that are resulting in "hot" spending time, are places that are "squeezed" as much as possible. Now what is "left" is places out of my reach, like the "WCF communication" performance, IIS Express VS IIS 7, Internet speed and DNS servers between, etc.

Comment: Something I have gotten when I used WCF is IOC container in your app. The first time, it will try to boot all your instances and wire them up. Some techniques like trying to lazy loading for this processing, I think you have to trying to investigate it as well